# How do I get all MAC addresses of all devices on my LAN that have an IP address (equivalent of doas nmap -sn but for IPv6)?

Tags: ipv6, nmap, mac-address, arp

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Give me your private IP and its mask";read given
if [[ "$given" =~ ^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{0,1}[0-9]{1,3} ]]; then
    echo "version 4"
    doas nmap -sn "$given"
    arp
else
    echo "version 6"
    prefix=${given::6}
    mask=$(echo "$given"|sed -E 's|.*(/[0-9]{1,3})|\1|')
    echo "$mask"
    echo "$prefix"
    doas nmap -6 -sn "$given" #halts, I have to press Ctrl-C
    doas nmap -6 --script=neighbors "$given" #does not work
    doas nmap -6 --script=neighbors "$prefix$mask" #does not work
    doas ip -6 neighbour #empty line, no results
fi
```

```
Give me your private IP and its mask
fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64
version 6
/64
fe80::
doas (j@j-AERO-17-KC) password: 
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-26 12:55 CET
Interrupt
doas (j@j-AERO-17-KC) password: 
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-26 12:59 CET
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:818: 'neighbors' did not match a category, filename, or directory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:818: in local 'get_chosen_scripts'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1310: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
doas (j@j-AERO-17-KC) password: 
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-26 12:59 CET
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:818: 'neighbors' did not match a category, filename, or directory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:818: in local 'get_chosen_scripts'
    /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1310: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

I replaced with `x` some of the digits of my address - for the sake of preserving my privacy.

**1.** Why does my script halt on `doas nmap -6 -sn "$given"` when an IPv6 address is given

**2.** `doas nmap -6 --script=neighbors "$prefix$mask"` was suggested by ChatGPT to me - why doesn't it work?

**3.** [Why doesn't](https://superuser.com/questions/374440/ndp-entries-on-linux) `doas ip -6 neighbour` work?

Comment: The IPv4 case is usually given a /24 => 256 scans to do. an IPv6 /64 means 2^64=18446744073709551616 scans to do with the same method. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Just enter the Network to nmap, it will take a very long time

```
nmap -6 fe80::/64
```

**2.** Does not make sense for me

**3.** "doas" needs a username ?

You need no extra rights to see the neighbours

```
ip -6 neighbour
```